# Weird behavior using bootstrap toggle

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I find my self having a really weird behaviour using `jQuery steps` and `bootstrap toggle`.
I really don't know if there's any connection between both but I know that there are at least many css problems if you're about to use jQuery plugins/extensions within `jQuery steps`.

I load content per `ajax` and use `partial views` using `@Html.Render()`

My problem:
If I don't load my `html markup` containing my `toggles` using `ajax` but place the code for `toggle inputs` directy in the (partial) view `toggles` won't work.
They are displayed correctly but simply don't react on any input.

If I do use `ajax` the `toggles` will not be displayed correctly without initializing per `javaScript`. If I do so they work but I don't want to always load my content using `ajax`.

Here is the code for the `partial view`:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input id="course" data-toggle="toggle" name="Rate.OfferingRates"  type="checkbox" >
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="offeringRateContainerSubscription">
            <div class="col-md-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="checkbox disabled">
                    <label>
                        <input id="subscription" disabled data-toggle="toggle" name="Rate.OfferingRates"  type="checkbox" value="@SlRateBaseTypes.Subscription">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        // reached 2 times using @Html.Render()
        debugger;
        $('#course').bootstrapToggle({
            on: 'Ja',
            off: 'Nein'
        });

        $('#subscription').bootstrapToggle({
            on: 'Ja',
            off: 'Nein'
        });

        $('#course').change(function () {
            debugger;
            var isCourse = $('#course').filter(":checked");
            if (isCourse.length) {
                $('#subscription').bootstrapToggle('enable');
                $('#subscription').parent().parent().parent().removeClass('disabled');
            } else {
                $('#subscription').bootstrapToggle('off');
                $('#subscription').bootstrapToggle('disable');
                $('#subscription').parent().parent().parent().addClass('disabled');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Moreover:
I placed a `debugger` mark in the javaScript in this `partial view` *MyPartialView* that initializes `toggles`

The `debugger` mark breaks two times when loading per `ajax`. I have no idea how this is possible.
I don't know if this is a problem either.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution to the problem.

**jQuery steps** internally renders again. 
Replacing the code in the .js file like suggested in 
https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/issues/42
worked for me!